# O eclipse não reconhece sdk?

Tags: android-eclipse

Como resolver esse problema em o eclipse não reconhece onde esta o sdk .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Menu do Eclipse, vá em: Windows > Preferences > Android, se o plugin do adt não estiver instalado, faça isso, depois selecione o diretório do sdk do Android.